# How to use the binary push notifications format by C?

Tags: c, apple-push-notifications

I use the The [Push Notification Binary Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) cmd=2

This is format :
[image: schema of frame binary format]

Q1: Can I send some device_id in one frame? For example:

item id = 1 , device_tocken #1

item id = 1 , device_tocken #2

item id = 1 , device_tocken #3

item id = 2 , message

item id = 3 ...
 and etc

Q2: How I can receive the response error ?

[image]

The documentation said: *If you send a notification that is accepted by APNs, nothing is returned.*

If I make **SSL_read** after **SSL_write** and package was accepted by APNs, the program is waiting in SSL_read command.

```
r = SSL_write(ssl, out_buffer, size);
int len = SSL_read(ssl, in_buff, 6);
```

If I read from ssl channel into single thread - I have segmentation fault.

Q3: Do You know the link to example of use this protocol?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not clear from the documentation, but I don't think you can send multiple device tokens in the same frame, simply because if you get an error response of an invalid device token, you won't be able to know which device token it refers to. If, on the other hand, your frame contains a single device token and a single message identifier, then an error response containing that message identifier will tell you exactly which message caused the error.
2. You should use a non-blocking read for attempting to read the error response. I don't know how you write that in C, but there must be a way to specify some timeout or to call a read method that specifies a timeout. If there is nothing to read, the method will return after the timeout is elapsed.
3. The APNS docs contain [samples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/LegacyFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH105-SW1) for sending notifications in the older formats (0 and 1). I suggest you use format 1 (which supports error responses), since I don't see any advantage of using the newer format 2.

Comment: 1. The practica says, that if send same items with different tockens, the message will to receive only last tocken device_id in the frame. In the my example, the device_id #3 have receive the push notification

Comment: 2. I use Open SSL API and I d't know as make nonblock connections into ssl connection.

Comment: @AlexandreKalendarev In that case there is no point in sending more than one device token in the same frame (since all but one of them will be ignored).

Comment: I used the format  0 & 1, but I must to have the ability to analyze the errors

Comment: If I use the format when cmd=1, how I can tu use info about identifier (bytes: 1-4)

Comment: @AlexandreKalendarev You send a notification with device token X and identifier Y. If later you read an error response with identifier Y, you know there was a problem with that notification. If the error code you get is 8, you know that device token X is invalid and you delete it from your DB. For that purpose you must maintain a list of recently sent notifications, in order to know which device token relates to which message identifier.

Comment: How I can read responce with code err is 8 from apns? The main problem is READING RESPONSE.